# pyinstaller - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.validators.table'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I try to convert a python script (plotly,plotly express)to an exe using Pyinstaller. i have the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.validators.table'".

[image]

would be great to get an idea of what I can do to solve this problem. thank you

Comment: What's the version of plotly and python??

Comment: plotly~=4.13.3   plotly-express~=0.4.1   and i installed on my venv also kaleido~=0.1.0.post1.  instead of orca which was required

Comment: and python version 3.9

Comment: @Bhavya Parikh any recommandations?

Comment: Nope sorry try to put issue on plotly forum from there you will get response!

Comment: thank you for your answer. first i will downgrade my plotly versions and try again